# Build Graph Printable String Information in ELF

Tags: ida, elf, strings

I'm new in the field of reverse engineering to detect malicious code in ELF file. I used IDA Pro to retrieve a list of strings in an elf file. But I wonder if IDA can build a graph showing the link between the strings (PSI)?

Answer (score 1):

have you checked out chart xrefsto it creates a graph

[image]

or you can use idc

and script a gdl file by getting the xrefsto to a certain address by improvising 
the script below

```
auto next,addr;
addr = ScreenEA();
next = MinEA();
next = DnextB(addr,next);
while( next != -1 ) {
Message("xref %x\n" , next);
next = DnextB(addr,next);
}
```